# Sort a lot of lists with small amount of code

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting

Is there a way to sort a lot of lists without having to write:

```
list.sort(list1)
list.sort(list2)
list.sort(list3)
...
```

for every single list?
It is very tedious when you have a lot of lists

Comment: why dont you add all list content first in one list and then sort that final list

Comment: Why do you have so many lists referenced by individual variables? Are they part of some bigger data structure?

Comment: I think your problem is to name the lists. No prob to build any loop around a list, a dictionary or any class.

Answer (score 3):

Probably best to use a `for`-loop:

```
lists = [1, 2, -1], [2, 0, 6], [91, 3, 82]    
for l in lists: l.sort()

list1, list2, list3 = lists
```

Now each list is sorted accordingly.

You could of course `map` it, but that's overkill since you'll also need to expand it into a list with `list` and dump away the resulting `None`s produced as a side-effect:

```
_ = list(map(list.sort, lists))
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't even Combine your lists to a named variable, so the code takes only 2 lines

```
l1 = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
l2 = [16,9,4,1]

#start of code
for my_l in [l1,l2]:
    list.sort(my_l)
#stop of code

print l1
print l2
```